# Using ncftp or other ftp command-line software to get directories

Tags: server, ftp

I'm transferring files from a FTP client to my ubuntu server using the terminal. I was able to upload a backup of some files that were already zipped but there are some files I need that are in a folder that can not be zipped or archived.

With NcFTP or other using another way, how can I transfer a folder of files (And sub-folders) without having to archived/zipped the folder? I am unable to do this because the files are on a shared hosting account for a game server and they're replying to slow while I'm asking them to archived it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well you don't say that there is strictly the need to use a command in the terminal in order to do the work so I guess what you wish is some terminal software which can handle ftp servers, such as a ftp client gui but for terminal purposes.

If I am right, I suggest you to give a chance to [**Midnight Commander**](http://www.midnight-commander.org/). Inside of which you will be able to connect to a ftp server in order to put or get files the same as folders (with files recursively).

Certain ftp server commands are allowed, such as the chmod for changing the permissions of the files/folders and there is the help of a dual tree window in which you can handle the contents of both your local device and remote server.

Here is a screenshot to illustrate:

[image]

This screenshots are taken in a unity desktop (12.04) but the same screens you'll find in terminal mode. Here is a step by step process in order to connect to a ftp. (Mouse supported only in GUI)

First let's hit F9 in order to get in the PullDown Menu. Let's go to the "Left" menu and choose "FTP Link" as shown.

[image]

The machine name will be asked, let's write in this box using the next format:

```
user:password@ftpserver.com
```

This will send your username and password to the desired ftp server. If everything runs ok you'll be able to see the contents of your ftp server on the left side of the Midnight Commander windows.

[image]

If you succeeded, let's hit the TAB window in order to move the pointer to the right pane, in which you can choose which files/folders (with files) you wish to copy, move, delete, etc. You may wish to read the manual before using midnight commander but it is quite easy to use indeed.

Midnight commander is a powerful application that can be installed directly from the terminal using the next command:

```
sudo apt-get install mc
```

Good luck!

Comment: Would this work through putty?

Comment: Is it a different question? This will work for FTP in the majority of the terminal emulators, nevertheless PuTTY may be different. Please give it a try and inform us if it works and if needed please open a new question in order to receive the proper support about PuTTY. Thank you.